# insert an item and sub item from list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

i have a problem with my list view, i display an item and subitem , i want to insert the two in database but it doesn't work !! the error is that i can't cast it to a text view
please someone help me.

This is the error that i get :

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TwoLineListItem cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

Here the code of List View :

```
    String[] databaseColumnNames = new String[] { DBAdapter.col_N_Ordre,DBAdapter.col_Nom_prénom};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursordapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2 , cursor, databaseColumnNames, toViewIDs);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    list.setAdapter(myCursordapter);
```

Here the code of insertion :

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int position, long arg3) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final String s = ((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
    db.insertest(s);
```

The query is :

```
   public long insertest(String region) {
      ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
          initialValues.put(col_Region,region);
      //initialValues.put(col_Provence_prefecture );
          return db.insert(MENAGE,null, initialValues);
  }
```

Comment: post your logcat and query for inserting data to database or relevant code

Comment: thanks Adrain for responding, i did the same code with one item and it worked fine, but when i decided to display two i did get this error whish is : can't cast it to a list view. How to solve that ??

Comment: where did you taken second value from listview?

Comment: That's the problem i don't know how to get the second value !? i tried to insert the both in one column . Do you have an idea how to proceed ?

Comment: what did you get in S variable when you click on listview item?

Comment: i did get nothing, i have error that i cant cast it to a text view ! i didn't have this problem when i displayed one item.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47491/discussion-between-andrain-and-utman-alami)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put following code in your listview item click listener

```
TextView v1 = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
String first = v1.getText().toString();
TextView v2 = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
String second = v2.getText().toString();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(DBAdapter.col_Region, first);
cv.put(DBAdapter._id, second);
myCursordapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
list.setAdapter(adapter); 

DBAdapter sql_Adapter = new DBAdapter(context);
sql_Adapter.open();

db.insertest(cv);
sql_Adapter.close();
```